# Using loc[] for i in range loops with pandas dataframes.

Tags: python, pandas

How can I loop through pandas's loc[] function such that given a long Series, I can break it into multiple little ones. Something I imagine would be like 
for i in range(1,10): 
   df.loc['2002-i-01:'2002-(i+1)-01']

Where i represents the number of months.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(100)), pd.date_range('2010-03-31', periods=100))
```

Observe that you are asking to slice from the beginning of one month to the beginning of the next.  Typical python slicing does not include the end point (though `loc` does).  I'll assume you meant to exclude it as that makes this answer convenient.

Use `resample` with a frequency `'M'`

```
df.resample('M').sum()

               A
2010-03-31     0
2010-04-30   465
2010-05-31  1426
2010-06-30  2295
2010-07-31   764
```

You can iterate through each month

```
for m, grp in df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')):
    # do stuff
    print(m)

2010-03-31 00:00:00
2010-04-30 00:00:00
2010-05-31 00:00:00
2010-06-30 00:00:00
2010-07-31 00:00:00
```